# Extracting parts from text with a vertical bar in r

Tags: r, text, extract

I need to create three variables from a text including vertical bars. The first variable should be the letters until the first vertical bar. The second variable should the combination of number and letters between two vertical bars, and the third variable should be information after "ADE."

I m not very familiar with the expressions so I tried a couple and failed.

Here is a three data points:

```
dat <- as.data.frame(c("A|3.ABC|ADE.5.26D","AB|3.ABD|ADE.5.26","B|3.BCD|ADE.5.45BD"))
colnames(dat) <- "text"

> dat
                text
1  A|3.ABC|ADE.5.26D
2  AB|3.ABD|ADE.5.26
3 B|3.BCD|ADE.5.45BD
```

I expect the output to be

```
v1 V2   V3
A  3.ABC 5.26D
AB 3.ABD 5.26
B  3.BCD 5.45BD
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the column with read.table, but remember that those were factors so first convert to character:

```
 dat2 <- read.table(text=as.character(dat$text), sep="|")

> dat2
  V1    V2         V3
1  A 3.ABC  ADE.5.26D
2 AB 3.ABD   ADE.5.26
3  B 3.BCD ADE.5.45BD
```

To remove ADE. use `sub`

```
dat2$V3 <- sub("ADE\\.", '', dat2$V3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `str_split` function from the `stringr` package:

```
as.data.frame(stringr::str_split(dat$text, '\\|', simplify = T))
  V1    V2         V3
1  A 3.ABC  ADE.5.26D
2 AB 3.ABD   ADE.5.26
3  B 3.BCD ADE.5.45BD
```

Comment: Thanks. For the V3, is there a quick way to get rid of "ADE."?

Comment: amisos55 you can use: `as.data.frame(stringr::str_split(dat$text, '\\|', simplify = T)) %>% dplyr::mutate(V3 = gsub("ADE.", "", V3)) ` to get rid of ADE.

Answer (score 0):

Just another approach:

```
dat <- as.data.frame(c("A|3.ABC|ADE.5.26D","AB|3.ABD|ADE.5.26","B|3.BCD|ADE.5.45BD"))
colnames(dat) <- "text"
tidyr::separate(dat, "text", into = paste0("V", 1:3), sep = "\\|") %>%
dplyr::mutate(V3 = gsub("ADE.", "", V3))
```